# Adding a significant amount of text elements in D3 causes performance issues

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm developing a D3 application that utilizes a lot of text. Since there is alot of text elements, panning around using D3 zoom causes some lag. Is there a way in which I can improve the performance of my application? I'm happy to hear any suggestions, you guys might have. I've been thinking about paginating my data and detecting pan events but my UI is very complex and the user has the freedom of placing things the way he wants so I am not sure how to go about implementing a pan/pagination solution.

Answer (score 1):

Such an open question is bound to get very opinion-based answers, and without more context you're also bound to get some useless ones, but here you go: it depends on what you want and what you mean by "a significant amount".

1. Supposing that significant amount is > 1000 elements, consider using canvas instead of SVG. Sure, if you can click on individual text nodes, that's more of a hassle, but it should be really good at panning/zooming.
2. If that is not possible, look at your code. Are you repositioning all text nodes individually? If so, place them all inside one `g` node and give that node a `transform` and `zoom`. In other words, make that node responsible for all global movement, and place the text nodes only relative to each other.
3. If that is also not possible, consider removing text nodes if they're outside the bounds of the SVG. Repositioning invisible nodes takes a lot of computation power, be smart about it. This is probably the most complex solution, so try it last.